# Differences between types of paper wallets at bitaddress.org

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet, bitaddress.org

What are the differences between the different types of paper wallets offered at bitaddress.org? I think the same question applies for the paper wallets offered at bitcoinpaperwallet.com.

On bitaddress.org, the options currently include:

- Single Wallet
- Paper Wallet
- Bulk Wallet
- Brain Wallet
- Vanity Wallet
- Split Wallet
- Wallet Details

[image: Screenshot from bitaddress.org]